# Setting up a differential model

Tags: word-problem

I'm confused on how I set up a differential model for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

A hot cup of coffee is placed in a room with a wack temperature control. The coffee at T(0) is 160 degrees F. After 1 hour, the coffee is 130 degrees F. The temp in the room after t hours is 40(1 + cos 0.5t) degrees F.

Comment: I this this question belongs to physics stackexchange...

Comment: @Viper6   Why did you delete the following topic after that I solved the problem for you?  
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831184  It's not fair. Restore please this topic.